# S-Function uint64_T input/output for simulink code generation error

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, s-function, tlc

I am attempting to generate C code with simulink coder for a model with an S-Function on Matlab 2020b. The S-Function contains an int64 input and an int64 output. The update diagram and simulink simulation work fine, therefore my s-function is valid. But C code generation with simulink coder indicates an error stating the maximum supported by the block for code generation is 32 bits, and in my tlc file i have the correct types in my function prototypes. In my S-Function i have also registered the 64 bits data types since SS_UINT64 and SS_INT64 does not exist.

Errore Code : Code cannot be generated for this model because block 'uint64_dummy_mdl/S-Function' is using data type 'int64' which requires 64 bits, but th emaximum supported by the block for code generation is 32

What am i missing? How can i generate the code using a 64 bit data type?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: consider posting at https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/

Answer (score 0):

Let's try configuring 64-bit target platform architecture for your model
(Configuration Parameters > Hardware Implementation > Device type)
I guess that having configured 32-bit target in Configuration Parameters could limit the uints to 32-bit representation.

Comment: You are answering with a question. If you need further clarification to the OP's question, then you should use the comments to ask your question. I recommend removing your answer or updating it so that it is actually an answer.